# g++ libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found after upgrade to gcc version 7.3.0 from 4.8.5

Tags: c++, g++, libstdc++

i guess the problem is that the g++ version 7.3.0 still using the old stdc lib , im not sure ..
how can i check ? and how can i upgrade to new versions as the runtime error im getting of the app
looks like this :

```
./a.out
./a.out: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./a.out)
./a.out: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

This is what i have now :

```
g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC)
```

this is my compile/link flags :

```
  g++ echo.cpp src/*.cpp -Wall -O0 -g -std=c++14  -I/home/vagrant/libuv/include -Isrc -L/home/vagrant/libuv/build -lssl -lcrypto  -Wl,--no-as-needed -Bstatic -luv_a -ldl -lpthread
```

and those are my stdc files after searching :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libstdc++.so
/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so
/home/vagrant/gcc-7.3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so
/home/vagrant/gcc-7.3.0/stage1-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so
/home/vagrant/gcc-7.3.0/prev-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so
```

Answer (score 2):

You dynamically linked the C++ standard library, then replaced it with a different version.

The version now installed on your computer is not compatible with the one your program requires, so it cannot run.

Rebuild your project, so that it links against the newer version, or downgrade GCC.

In future you may wish to consider statically linking the standard library instead, so that this particular version is just bundled with your executable. But this has downsides (which you can research).